# JQUERY update Tabs when datepicker field change

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

I've a Jquery's UI datepicker and some UI Tabs displaying some datas via AJAX (in ASP.NET 1.1...), I would like to update all Tabs object when I select a new date.

Could everyone help me?????

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getId(){
    var TabSel = $('#tabs').tabs('tabsselect').val();
    return TabSel
}
function getDate(){
    var dataPick = $('#datepicker').val();
    return dataPick
}
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.extend({showMonthAfterYear: false}, $.datepicker.regional['it']));
        $("#datepicker").datepicker(
        {showOn: 'button', defaultDate: '-1w', showDefault: true, buttonImage: 'images/cal.gif', buttonImageOnly: false,
            altField: '#alternate', altFormat: 'yymmdd'}
        );

        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
               //change the tabs here.
                $('#tabs').tabs({ 
                spinner: '<b>Caricamento in corso....</b>',
                ajaxOptions: { data: { id: getId, seldate: getDate}}
                });

            }
            });
    });
</script>
</HEAD>
<body>
    <div class="demo">
        <p>Data: <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="01/10/2009" ><input type="hidden" id="alternate" >   
        </p><br>    
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="Tab1.aspx" id="Tab1">Tab1</a>
                <li>
                    <a href="Tab2.aspx" id="Tab2">Tab2</a>
                <li>
                    <a href="Tab3.aspx" id="Tab3">Tab3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End demo -->
</body>
```

Thanks a lot.

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

Implement the tab changes in the onSelect method of the jQuery Datepicker.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
       //change the tabs here.
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Esk. I've tried your code, but I think I still make some errors.

I've update my question with the code....

Thanks 4 your help!

Alessandro